# Incluir link caso seja primeiro elemento

Tags: javascript, jquery

Possuo um menu com quatro itens. O menu é gerenciável, não é feito manual via HTML.

Quero modificar um link no primeiro item do Menu, tenho como fazer isso com Jquery? Não sei nem como procurar para fazer isso.

Por exemplo:

```
<li class='classe' onclick='window.location=\"/paginaSYS\"'><a href='/paginaSYS'>tituloSYS</a></li>
```

Com esse código de cima, e com o gerenciador eu consigo gerar os quatro itens do menu, porém quero inserir um link quando o usuário clicar no primeiro item.

Eu quero que quando o usuário clique no primeiro item do Menu, ele não abra o html gerado pelo gerenciador, mas sim uma URL que eu ordenar.

Se ele clicar em 
ITEM 1 - não enviar para a página gerada pelo gerenciador. www.site.com/menu1
quero que envie para um endereço que eu desejar.

Pensei em fazer um redirecionamento.

Comment: Seja um pouco mais específico. Você deseja adicionar 1 link em 1 primeiro texto que vier, ou você deseja adicionar 1 ítem que fique como primeiro da lista?
Ex: Posso criar um <a> e deixar como primeiro da lista ou pegar o primeiro<a> da lista e adicionar o atributo href="o que quiser" mesmo que o href="" seja vazio no início do elemento.

Comment: Não sei se apenas para mim, mas creio que sua duvida não tenha ficado clara o suficiente. Poderia editar e tentar ser mais específico por gentileza?

Comment: Acabo de editar, me digam se ficou melhor de entender agora.

Answer (score 4):

Talvez algo assim:

```
// Delega um evento de clique para a primeira âncora do menu mesmo que tenha sido criada após o primeiro carregamento do DOM.
$(document).on('click', '#menu a:first', function(event) {

    // Previne que a ação padrão da âncora (O redirecionamento) seja executada.
    event.preventDefault();

    // Redireciona o documento atual para outro URL.
    document.location = 'http://example.com';

});
```

Comment: Ainda não está funcionando. Eu criei um ID chamado #primeiro, apenas para ele pegar o primeiro elemento com o Jquery que você passou.

Comment: Talvez adaptar o seletor ajude... Pode colar um pedaço da estrutura HTML do menu para facilitar?

Comment: Oi. Esse é o HTML.
<li class='paginapadraoMenuBt paginapadraoMenuDupSel paginapadraoMenuDup' onclick='window.location=\"/paginaSYSurlSYS\"'><a href='/paginaSYSurlSYS'>tituloSYS</a></li>

Answer (score 3):

Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/uASJ9/

Fiz da seguinte maneira:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#menu a:first" ).attr( "href", "http://pt.stackoverflow.com" );
});
```

Comment: Fiz isso:

<li id='primeiro' class='paginapadraoMenuDup' onclick='window.location=\"/paginaSYSurlSYS\"'><a href='/paginaSYSurlSYS'>tituloSYS</a></li>

E no Jquery
$( "#primeiro a:first" ).attr( "href", "http://www.google.com.br/" ); mas não funcionou

Comment: Não sei por qual motivo você tem um onclick, não utilize eventos chamados inline. Prefira usar no próprio jQuery. Dá uma olhada aqui, fiz com ul e li para você: http://jsfiddle.net/uASJ9/1/

Comment: boa Ronny, simples!

Answer (score 2):

Consegui resolver com o seguinte código:

```
$(".paginapadraoMenuBt:first").attr( "onclick", "window.open('http://www.google.com.br')");
```

Comment: Argh! Por que substituir o atributo? Eu usaria a solução do Diego.